# Failed to build IoTivity for raspberry on Ubuntu

Tags: iotivity

I'm trying to build IoTivity for raspberry with Yocto but get a lot of compile errors like:

`'bind' is not a member of 'std'`

```
resource/include/IClientWrapper.h:51:25: error: 'FindResListCallback' has not been declared
                         FindResListCallback& callback,
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and many more

Any help?

Comment: Please specify repository link, version which you are using, and which command did you enter.

Comment: git clone -b git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky.git
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-raspberrypi
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-oic

and after setting sources I call: "bitbake iotivity" to build only iotivity, but even if I call "bitbake rpi-basic-image" to build everything I get the same error message

Comment: try version 1.2.1 of meta-oic

Answer (score 0):

We have prepared a detailed guide on how to build iotivity for yocto.
Please refer to this link.

https://wiki.iotivity.org/yocto